# Error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level when I reworked small part of REACT code to REDUX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have React app which have page with Post. But now I rework this app to Redux.

And when in file `Post.js` I rework this small part:

```
useEffect(() => {
        fetchListCategory(); 
    }, []);
    
    async function fetchListCategory() {
        const dataCategories = await api(`${listRoute}?limit=100`, {
          method: 'GET',
         });
          setValue(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            listCategories: dataCategories.data,
         }));
     }
```

to Redux:

```
useEffect(() => {
        fetchListCategory()(dispatch); 
    }, []);
    
    function fetchListCategory() {
       return async (dispatch) => {
           dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_START_SELECT" }); 
             const dataCategories = await api(`${listRoute}?limit=100`, {
                method: 'GET',
             });
           dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_END_SELECT", payload: dataCategories });
    }
```

I get error in file `Post.js` in line `export default Post;`:

> 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

#### How to fix this error?

### P.S.Now below in question I will write some part of file `Post.js`, and his `children components`. If you need more information write in the comments, I send for you screenshot or I add more information in question.

### Post.js:

```
const Post = () => {
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const listImage = useSelector(state => state.filterImageReducer.listImage);
 
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchListCategory()(dispatch); 
    }, []);
    
    function fetchListCategory() {                  
       return async (dispatch) => {
           dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_START_SELECT" }); 
             const dataCategories = await api(`${listRoute}?limit=100`, {
                method: 'GET',
             });
           dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_END_SELECT", payload: dataCategories });
    }

   useEffect(() => {
      fetchDataPost()(dispatch);
   }, []);
    
    function fetchDataPost() {
       return async (dispatch) => {
           dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_START_POSTS" }); 
             const data = await apiImage(`${imageRoute}?orderBy=created_at`, {
               method: 'GET',
             });
           dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_END_POSTS", payload: data }); 
        }
    }
  
  return (
     <div>
        <DisplayPost dataAttribute={listImage}/>
        <AddPost fetchDataPost={fetchDataPost}/>
        <EditPost fetchDataPost={fetchDataPost}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missing `}` where `fetchListCategory` function is not properly terminated which is why you get this error.

```
 function fetchListCategory() {                  
       return async (dispatch) => {
           dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_START_SELECT" }); 
             const dataCategories = await api(`${listRoute}?limit=100`, {
                method: 'GET',
             });
           dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA_END_SELECT", payload: dataCategories });
    }
} <- an extra bracket here
```

Also assuming you are using redux-thunk as a middleware, you do can simply dispatch fetchListCategory like

```
dispatch(fetchListCategory());
```

instead of

```
fetchListCategory()(dispatch);
```

Also you can take out the implementation of fetchListCategory outside of your component

Comment: thank you very much! I three hours can not find reason of my error.